# How to query multiple tables in EF ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have a big beginner Problem i think! I try to make a ASP.NET MVC 5 Applikation, the application should store Suppliers in a database table, in seperate table it should store SalesOrders. In the View, when i click on details of the Supplier, all details should be load, but also all SalesOrders where for this Supplier should be load too. i've tried this way without result.

ModelBase Contains an prop ID only.

The Classes

```
public class SalesOrder : ModelBase
{
    public string ordertitle { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
}


public class Supplier : ModelBase
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Discount { get; set; }
}
```

The ViewModel

```
public class SalesOrderViewModel
{
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public List<SalesOrder> SalesOrder { get; set; }
}
```

The Controller

```
public ActionResult SupplierSalesOrders(int id)
{
    var supplier = _context.Suppliers.Single(s => s.Id == id);
    var salesorder = _context.SalesOrders.ToList().Where(s => s.Supplier == supplier);

    SalesOrderViewModel viewModel = new SalesOrderViewModel
    {
        Supplier = supplier,
        SalesOrder = salesorder.ToList()
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

The View

```
@model NETwork.Models.SalesOrderViewModel


@foreach(var sales in Model)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SalesOrder)
}
```

sorry for the loooong question.

What ive done wrong?

best regards

Lars

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is you would usually query by Id

```
.Where(s => s.Supplier == supplier);
```

The above is not an id, is an object of `supplier`

One solution would be to include the collection navigation property for `SalesOrders` in `Supplier`

```
public class Supplier : ModelBase
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Discount { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SalesOrder> SalesOrders { get; set; }
}
```

Which then allows

```
 var supplier = _context.Suppliers
                        .Include(x => SalesOrders)
                        .Single(s => s.Id == id);


 SalesOrderViewModel viewModel = new SalesOrderViewModel
 {
      Supplier = supplier,
      SalesOrder = supplier.SalesOrder
 };
```

Note that, the above *viewModel* is probably not ideal. Meaning, `supplier` will naturally contain all the `salesorders` in this incarnation and `SalesOrder = supplier.SalesOrder` will be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Foreign key to the `SalesOrder` class for the supplier.

```cs
public class SalesOrder : ModelBase
{
    public string ordertitle { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Supplier))]
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }

    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
}
```

And you can add a collection of Sales orders to the suppliers.

```cs
public class Supplier : ModelBase
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Discount { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SalesOrder> SalesOrders { get; set; }
}
```

Then, if you would like to get the Sales orders with the supplier, you can use the Include() action when you query the supplier.

```cs
var supplier = _context.Suppliers.Include(s => s.SalesOrders).Single(s => s.Id == id);
```